# SQL - Testing dB

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL database that is not setup correctly. I need a Query that will help me find out where.

Two tables
Table1.xyz_ID
Table2.xyz_ID

Some entries in Table1.xyz_ID have no corresponding field in Table2.xyz_ID  What is the SQL to sort Table2 entries that are in error?

Comment: Provide some sample data and expected output into the question.

Comment: MySQL workbench and other tools can do schema comparisons and generate sql to synchronize the schemas for you. That being said if it is a one off or infrequent task then you can use information_schema tables/views.

Answer (score 1):

```
select t1.xyz_ID
from Table1 t1
left join Table2 t2
  on t1.xyz_ID = t2.xyz_ID
where t2.xyz_ID is null
```

Provides all IDs that are in Table1 but not in Table 2

Comment: That looks good. Thank you Sir Monkey.
I guess I'll have to break down and learn about 'Joins'